# colcon build problem

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ros2-launch

```
qrie@qrie-HP-Laptop-15-rb0xx:~/_ws$ colcon build
Starting >>> control_msgs
Starting >>> ros2_control_test_assets       
Finished <<< ros2_control_test_assets [1.66s]                     
Starting >>> controller_manager_msgs
--- stderr: controller_manager_msgs                               
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:59 (message):
  execute_process(/home/qrie/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m rosidl_adapter
  --package-name controller_manager_msgs --arguments-file
  /home/qrie/_ws/build/controller_manager_msgs/rosidl_adapter__arguments__controller_manager_msgs.json
  --output-dir
  /home/qrie/_ws/build/controller_manager_msgs/rosidl_adapter/controller_manager_msgs
  --output-file
  /home/qrie/_ws/build/controller_manager_msgs/rosidl_adapter/controller_manager_msgs.idls)
  returned error code 1:

  AttributeError processing template 'msg.idl.em'

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 48, in evaluate_template
      _interpreter = em.Interpreter(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'Interpreter'

  

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
               ^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/main.py", line 53, in main
      abs_idl_file = convert_to_idl(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 19, in convert_to_idl
      return convert_msg_to_idl(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/msg/__init__.py", line 39, in convert_msg_to_idl
      expand_template('msg.idl.em', data, output_file, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 23, in expand_template
      content = evaluate_template(template_name, data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 69, in evaluate_template
      _interpreter.shutdown()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shutdown'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< controller_manager_msgs [1.47s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< control_msgs [3.28s]

Summary: 1 package finished [8.81s]
  1 package failed: controller_manager_msgs
  1 package aborted: control_msgs
  2 packages had stderr output: control_msgs controller_manager_msgs
  62 packages not processed
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/63) the reason could be that packages `em` and `empy` build under the same namespace, so a solution provided there is:

`pip uninstall em`

`pip install empy==3.3.4`

or perhaps simply installing this version of `empy` or any version below 4.0 [[source]](https://github.com/lopsided98/nix-ros-overlay/issues/340) will do the trick.

Edit:

Possibly relevant link for future debugging: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/779